# define textarea as required with mojolicious tag helper

Tags: perl, mojolicious

How do i define an textarea as required with mojolicious tag helper?

I need to generate a textarea like this

```
<textarea name="comment" required></textarea>
```

When trying to do the same with tag helper

```
%= text_area 'comment', 'required'
```

I get

```
<textarea name="comment">required</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mojo tag helpers will simply pass extra attributes through (see `sub _tag` in [the source](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugin/TagHelpers.txt)).

In HTML5, an empty attribute can be declared as `attr=""` ([docs here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty)).

So, based on the [Mojo text_area docs](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugin/TagHelpers#text_area), the syntax would be:

```
%= text_area 'comment', required => ''
```

Comment: but this produces   <textarea name="comment" required=""></textarea>. This is not the same as   <textarea name="comment" required></textarea>

Comment: According to the HTML5 spec they are the same. I am not aware of any way to create empty attributes in mojo. Best.

Comment: You are right www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute. If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace

Answer (score 1):

```
%= text_area 'comment', required => '1'
```

[here](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugin/TagHelpers#text_area)

Comment: Please turn this into an answer. Make yourself comfortable with the editing tools, give it some love.

Comment: I looked in the hrml5 spec and it does not look like a valid option  www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute. If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace, so 1 is not valid but required => 'required' is one